# Deleting an element from a JavaScript array

Tags: javascript

I am deleting an element from an array using `delete`

I ave this object:

```
obj = {
    Variables: [ {
        Name: "test",
        Type: "Int",
        Control: "U",
        Value: "123"
    }, {
        Name: "ftr",
        Type: "DateTime",
        Control: "UA",
        Value: "123123"
    }, {
        Name: "wertwe",
        Type: "Int",
        Control: "SA",
        Value: "435345"
    } ]
};
```

using this code:

```
 delete data["Variables"][2];
```

Now obj contains the value:

```
{"Variables":[{"Name":"test","Type":"Int","Control":"U","Value":"123"},{"Name":"ftr","Type":"DateTime","Control":"UA","Value":"123123"},null]}
```

Is there any way to delete an element without a null value appearing in the object?

Comment: @Teemu obj is the json object

Comment: This isn't a JSON array, this is JavaScript array.

Comment: Nope, it's a JavaScript object, it has nothing to do with data interchange formats.

Answer (score 0):

You punctured a hole in the array. You will need to use `splice` to remove the hole. I found the dupe after writing this answer so I'm going to vote to close with the Q/A where the example is.